# Binding resp. DataTemplate confusion

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am still very new and trying my first serious data binding. I have read a lot about how it works, am just struggling with this concrete example. I have tried to read all links I could find on this, but most sources tend to be a bit imprecise at key spots. So here goes:

-My Application generates dynamically a variable 'PlayerList' of type 'List', where 'Player' is a complex object.

-I want to display this in a ListBox via Binding. Obvoiusly, since Player is a complex Object I want to create a DataTemplate for it. So I have something like this in the 'Window1.xaml':

```
<ListBox 
    Name="ListBox_Players" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PlayerListResource}}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PlayerTemplate}">
</ListBox>
```

and something like this in the 'App.xaml':

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PlayerTemplate">  <!-- DataType="{x:Type Player}" --> 
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}"/>
      <TextBlock Text=", "/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=nrOfTabls}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Of course, this template will become more verbose later. So as you see above, I have tried to create a resource for the PlayerList variable, but have not managed yet, i.e., smthn. like this

```
<src: XXX x:Key="PlayerListResource"/>
```

where for XXX as I understand it I should enter the class of the Resource variable. I tried

```
List<Player>, List<src:Player>
```

etc., but obv. XAML has trouble with the '<,>' characters.

I also have another problem: By not declaring a resource but by direct binding (i.e., in C# writing "ListBox_Players.ItemsSource=PlayerList;") and deleting the 'ItemTemplate' declaration and overwriting the ToString() method of the Player class to output the name of the Player I have managed to see that the binding works (i.e., I get a list of Player names in the ListBox). But then, if I insert the template again, it displays only ','my Template does not work!

Comment: Can you post the code for the Player and the C# code corresponding to the XAML above? (E.g. if the above XAML is in MailWindow.xaml, then post MainWindow.xaml.cs)

Comment: Hey ikh, my .cs is long, but the parts concerning this problem are nothing special. As I wrote below, It seems to be resolved by replacing the fields in the class by properties. I have though not found a single source telling me that the internal things of an object instance that I can bind are prorepties and not only fields. This would indeed be yet another very convincing reason to use properties always!

Comment: But what about the other question, I.e., if I wanted to add a reference to the 'PlayerList' of class List<Player>. How do I do it in XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you're getting just commas without anything else suggests to me that either the names of `Player` members do not match the names in `Path=` in the `DataTemplate` (I had this problem at one point), or the relevant `Player` members are inaccessible.

I just tested what you've shown of your code so far, and it seemed to work fine.  The only change I made was change this line:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PlayerListResource}}"
```

to this line:

```
ItemsSource = "{Binding}"
```

This tells the program that it'll get the ItemsSource at run time.

My `Player` class was:

```
class Player {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int nrOfTabls { get; set; }
}
```

and my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` was:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    private ObservableCollection<Player> players_;

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        players_ =new ObservableCollection<Player> () {
            new Player() {
                name = "Alex",
                nrOfTabls = 1,
            },
            new Player() {
                name = "Brett",
                nrOfTabls = 2,
            },
            new Player() {
                name="Cindy",
                nrOfTabls = 231,
            }
        };

        ListBox_Players.ItemsSource = players_;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey ikh, thanks for your efforts! If you take a look at your code you did exactly what I speculated in the last lines of my question: Your 'name' and 'nrOfTabls' are PROPERTIES and not FIELDS. I tried it a couple of minutes ago, and voila, the binding worked. So it seems you can only bind Properties of an object instance, not fields. Is that generally true?

Comment: @ToaoG Whoa, I was not aware that this does not work on properties!  Reflection treats properties differently from fields, so that may be why.

Comment: Just to clarify, because you wrote the contrary, it does work on properties, but not on fields.